# MVC cascading dropdown

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables a Manufacturer table and ManufacturerModel table. I am trying to populate two dropdown lists. A list of Manufacturers and then based off of what manufacturer is selected it will bring up a list of Models. But what I implemented doesn't work. It doesn't do anything.

I created a new ViewModel incorporating the two models

```
public class ManufacturerModelDD
{
    public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManufacturerModel> ManufacturerModels { get; set; }
}
```

And I have created 2 functions in the controller I want them in.

```
ManufacturerModelDD mm = new ManufacturerModelDD();

    public JsonResult GetManufacturers()
    {
        return Json(mm.Manufacturers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetModelsByManufacturerID(string manufacuterId)
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(manufacuterId);

        var models = from a in mm.ManufacturerModels where a.ManufacturerID == Id select a;

        return Json(models);
    }
```

In my view I have

```
<script>
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Device/GetManufacturers",
    datatype: "Json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#dropdownManufacturer').append('<option value="' + value.ManufacturerID + '">' +
            value.Manufacturer1 +'</option>');
        });
    }
});

    $('#dropdownManufacturer').change(function(){
        $('#dropdownModel').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Device/GetModelsByManufacturerID",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { manufacturerID: $('#dropdownManufacturer').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownModel').append('<option value="' + value.ManufacturerID + '">' +
                        value.Model + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: which part is not working ?

Comment: I'm not sure. My dropdowns are blank. I'm not sure if it is my functions or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

`ManufacturerModelDD` is a class which does not inherit from `DbContext`. So i am not sure 
an object of that class can be used to access the entities.

You may consider createing an object of your db context class and access your entity data.
Assuming your db context class looks like this

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManufacturerModel> ManufacturerModels { get; set; }
}
```

You may use an object of this class.

```
public JsonResult GetManufacturers()
{
    var db = new YourDbContext();
    var data = db.Manufacturers
               .Select(s=> new {Id =s.ManufacturerID ,
                                                 Name = s.ManufacturerName}).ToList();
    return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And make sure you use the correct properties when looping through the data.

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#dropdownManufacturer').append('<option value="' + value.Id+ '">' +
        value.Name+'</option>');
    });
}
```

Also, make sure you have your view specific javascript code under the scrips section

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
     $(function(){
         //your code goes here.
     });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: I have made sure that my code looks exactly like above and still nothing. Could it be with my dropdown - @Html.DropDownList("dropdownManufacturer", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a manufacturer", new { @style = "width:250;" })

Comment: Just tried the same code and it worked. Are you sure `db.Manufacturers` returns something ? Open up your browser console and look for js errors also

Comment: Does it matter what jquery version you use and/or what order you put them in?

Comment: do you have any js errors ? Is it making the ajax call ? Check your network console

Comment: is your script inside the script section ? Check my update in the answer

Comment: I put it inside the Section Script and still nothing. How do I check to see if it is making the ajax call? Thank-you for being so patient and working with me on this.

Comment: Open your browser Dev tools and check network and console tabs please

Comment: There is nothing happening under either tab

Comment: I had to go to FireFox to see what was going on. It looks like it is performing the GET method over and over with a status of 200.

Comment: @EthelPatrick check whether the response body has any items. It not, your server code is not retuning items. You need to check your db table

Comment: I put in an error: function(error) to send an alert to see if the ajax is working and it gave me the ajax error - Error ajax not working (object, object)

Comment: Inspect those object And you will be able to see what is wrong.